# Retrieve element values from xml

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following code:

```
XmlDocument doc = //A ton of code that generates the document"

XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("ElementINeed");

string ElementINeedValue;

foreach(XmlElement node in nodes)
{
    ElementINeedValue = node.Value;
}
```

When I debug the code, `node.Value > innerText` holds the correct information I'm trying to get from the XML document. Problem is I can't save it, `ElementINeedValue` remains null

Comment: can you share a minimal reproducible example?how you check `ElementINeedValue`? note that ``ElementINeedValue`` is inside loop, may be the last value of node.Innertext is null.

Comment: Instead of `node.Value` use `node.InnerText`.

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderPetrov, works.